# clojure-spec: Unable to get function's postcondition right

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I'm trying [clojure spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) on a simple function that computes the "neighbours" of a (row,col) position in a square matrix. For example for the 4x4 matrix given below, the neighbours of cell (1,1) shall be: (0,1), (1,0), (1,2), (2,1). The neighbours of cell (4,3), which is not even in the matrix' range, shall be (3,3) etc.

[image: 4x4 square matrix and two positions with their neighbours]

The function's input is the size of the matrix and the (row,col) of the position of interest. The output is a collection of (row,col) of the neighbours. This collection can be empty if there are no neighbours.

This problem can be found in "The Joy of Clojure, 2nd editions, page 94; but this code is modified because the original was too compact for me. Then I tried to spec it and check the spec in the `:pre` and `:post` parts.

However, I don't get the `:post` part to work. When I run the test cases, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast
to clojure.lang.IFn
```

What to change?

```
(require '[clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
         '[clojure.test       :as t])

; ===
; Specs
; ===

(s/def ::be-row-col
       (s/coll-of integer? :count 2 :kind sequential?))
(s/def ::be-square-matrix-size
       (s/and integer? #(<= 0 %)))
(s/def ::be-row-col-vector
       (s/and (s/coll-of ::be-row-col) (s/int-in-range? 0 5 #(count %))))

; ===
; Function of interest
; ===

(defn neighbors [sqmsz rc]

     {:pre  [(s/valid? ::be-row-col rc)
             (s/valid? ::be-square-matrix-size sqmsz)] 
      :post [(s/valid? ::be-row-col-vector %)]
     }

     (let [ cross             [[-1 0] [1 0] [0 -1] [0 1]]
            in-sq-matrix?     (fn [x]
                                  (and (<= 0 x) (< x sqmsz)))
            in-sq-matrix-rc?  (fn [rc]
                                  (every? in-sq-matrix? rc))
            add-two-rc        (fn [rc1 rc2]
                                  (vec (map + rc1 rc2)))
            get-rc-neighbors  (fn [rc]
                                  (map (partial add-two-rc rc) cross)) ]
        (filter in-sq-matrix-rc? (get-rc-neighbors rc))))

; ===
; Put a collection of [row col] into an expected form
; ===
; this is used to run the test code

(defn formify [rc-coll]
   (let [ cmp (fn [rc1 rc2]
                  (let [ [r1 c1] rc1
                         [r2 c2] rc2 ]
                     (cond (< r1 r2) -1  ; sort by row
                           (> r1 r2) +1
                           (< c1 c2) -1  ; then by column
                           (> c1 c2) +1
                           true       0))) ]
      (vec (sort cmp rc-coll))))

; ===
; Testing
; ===

(defn test-nb [ sqmsz rc expected txt ]
   (do
      (t/is (= (formify (neighbors sqmsz rc)) expected) txt)
   ))

(test-nb  0  [0 0]  []  "Zero-size matrix, outside #1")    
(test-nb  0  [1 1]  []  "Zero-size matrix, outside #2")    
(test-nb  1  [0 0]  []  "One-size matrix, inside")    
(test-nb  1  [1 0]  [[0 0]]  "One-size matrix, outside")    
(test-nb  5  [0 0]  [[0 1] [1 0]]  "Testing top left")    
(test-nb  5  [1 0]  [[0 0] [1 1] [2 0]]  "Testing left edge")    
(test-nb  5  [1 1]  [[0 1] [1 0] [1 2] [2 1]]  "Testing middle #1")    
(test-nb  5  [2 2]  [[1 2] [2 1] [2 3] [3 2]]  "Testing middle #2")    
(test-nb  5  [3 3]  [[2 3] [3 2] [3 4] [4 3]]  "Testing middle #3")    
(test-nb  5  [4 4]  [[3 4] [4 3]]  "Testing btm right")    
(test-nb  5  [5 5]  []  "Testing outside #1")    
(test-nb  5  [5 4]  [[4 4]]  "Testing outside #2")    
(test-nb  5  [4 3]  [[3 3] [4 2] [4 4]]  "Testing btm edge")
```

Comment: After further editing and experimentation, functioning code can be found [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/dtonhofer/c8f269d688ed509b81603e43b7310d43)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the `#` prefix to make your anonymous function in the `:post` condition. The post condition needs to be a function that can take the output of the subject function's invocation.

```
:post [#(s/valid? ::be-row-col-vector %)]
```

Could also be rewritten as:

```
:post [(fn [o] (s/valid? ::be-row-col-vector o))]
```

But depending on your use case, you may want to look into [function specs](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_specing_functions) and [`instrument`](https://clojure.org/guides/spec#_instrumentation_and_testing) as an alternative to `:pre` and `:post` conditions. I wrote more [examples here.](https://blog.taylorwood.io/2017/10/15/fspec.html)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Evidently my brain is not used to the syntax yet. Function specs will be attempted soon.